# How to open Settings.bundle in Finder

Tags: xcode, finder, settings-bundle

I want to be able to add files to Settings.bundle folder using Finder but I'm unable to do so because Finder recognizes Settings.bundle as a file.

How do I view/edit the contents of Settings.bundle using Finder?

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the file and choose **Show package contents** or use **Go->Go to folder** option using the bundle path.